# Prove there exists a branch of logarithm on $\Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, branch-cuts

Let $\Omega=\{e^{x+iy}: x\in(1,10),~ |y-x|<1\}$. Show that there exists a branch $L$ of logarithm defined on $\Omega$. Also, how many values does the difference $(\log − L)$ take, where $\log$ is the principal branch of logarithm?

I showed that $0\notin\Omega$ and $0<\arg z<\arctan 2,$ and defined $L(z)=\log r +i\theta~$ for $0<\theta <\arctan2$. This shows that $L$ is the branch on $\Omega$. Now for the difference $(\log −L)$: since $\log$ assumes arguments in $(-\pi, \pi)$, we conclude that $(\log −L)$ assumes arguments in $(-\pi-\arctan2,\pi)$. Since $2\pi<\pi-(-\pi-\arctan2)<4\pi$, the difference takes two values. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

For a branch of the logarithm to be defined, it is enough for $\Omega$ to be simply connected and exclude $0$.
As you mention, $0\notin \Omega$.
To see that $\Omega$ is simply connected, note that it is the image of the restricted exponential
\begin{align*}
f\colon U &\longrightarrow \Omega \\
z &\longmapsto e^z,
\end{align*}
where $U = \{x + i y : x \in (1, 10), \lvert x - y\rvert < 1\}$ is simply connected since it is convex.

To see that $f$ is injective, suppose that $f(x + iy) = f(x' + iy')$.
Then $x = x'$ and $y = y' + 2\pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbf{Z}$.
But notice that, since $x + iy, x' + iy' \in U$,
$$
|y - y'|
= |y - x - (y' - x')|
\leq |y - x| + |y' - x'|
< 2,
$$
which means that $k = 0$ so that $y = y'$, and so $f$ is injective.
It's also surjective by the definition of $\Omega$.

Moreover, the exponential map is continuous an open, so $f$ is a homeomorphism.
Thus $\Omega$ is homeomorphic to $U$ and so is simply connected.
Hence, it admits a branch of the logarithm.

---

Given that the $e^{x + iy}$ representation of elements of $\Omega$ is unique over $x +  i y \in U$, any branch of the complex logarithm over $\Omega$ must be of the form $L(e^{x + iy}) = x + i(y + 2\pi k)$ for some $k \in \mathbf{Z}$.

On the other hand, the principal value of the logarithm satisfies, for $x + iy \in U$,
\begin{align*}
\log(e^{x + i y})
= \begin{cases}
x + i y &\text{if } y\in (0, \pi], \\
x + i(y - 2\pi) &\text{if } y\in (\pi, 3\pi],\\
x + i(y - 4\pi) &\text{if } y\in (3\pi, 11).
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have that
\begin{align*}
\log(e^{x + i y}) - L(e^{x + i y})
= \begin{cases}
-2\pi k i &\text{if } y\in (0, \pi], \\
-2\pi(k+1) i &\text{if } y\in (\pi, 3\pi],\\
-2\pi(k+2) i &\text{if } y\in (3\pi, 11).
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

That is, $\log(z) - L(z)$ takes $3$ distinct values on $\Omega$.

Comment: In the problem $x\in(1,10)$, while you took $x\in(0,10)$.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - fixed now, but it doesn't change anything.